# Why is this the right way to iterate through subwidgets of a MultiWidget?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use a MultiWidget form in Django. I want to use a custom template for this widget, in which I include the basic built-in templates of my subwidgets (two simple TextInputs).
And I was blocked for some time on this.

In order to include the templates of the two TextInput subwidgets, it seemed more clever to import the built-in ones that rewriting two HTML input tags myself. I spent a lot of time trying to understand why this wouldn't work:

```html
{% for subwidget in widget.subwidgets %}
    {% include subwidget.template_name %}
{% endfor %}
```

The HTML code created with that loop would be:

```html
<input type="" name="f" class="" required id="id_f" />
<input type="" name="f" class="" required id="id_f" />
```

And fail to work as intended: the input values wouldn't be compressed properly and the fields would both be set to the fallback value of the decompress method.

Conversely,with no custom template, my multiwidget worked like a charm, with two fonctioning TextInputs rendered automatically by Django.

I then had the idea I should have had at the very first: take a look at the built-in Django multiwidget HTML template! Surprise, the code looks a lot like mine:

```html
{% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}
    {% include widget.template_name %}
{% endfor %}
```

This renders the following HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="f_0" label="latitude" class="" required id="id_f_0" />
<input type="text" name="f_1" label="longitude" class="" required id="id_f_1" />
```

Which works perfectly (i.e. the values entered are getting passed and compressed/decompressed correctly). I believe it's due to the unique HTML ids.

So, in a way, I've found the answer to my problem. The issue is I don't understand why my first version of the loop didn't work exactly the same! It may even be my understanding of Python which could be insufficient here, but it seems to be that the words 'subwidget' and 'widget' in the first and the second loop represent the same object: an item of the iterable widget.subwidgets. And as such, there should be no difference in the two loops' behaviour.

To put this to the test, I tried that:

```html
{% for subwidget in widget.subwidgets %}
    {{ subwidget }} </br>
{% endfor %} </br>
{% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}
    {{ widget }} </br>
{% endfor %}
```

The output was the same for both loops:

```html
{'name': 'f_0', 'is_hidden': False, 'required': False, 'value': None, 'attrs': {'label': 'latitude', 'class': '', 'required': True, 'id': 'id_f_0'}, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/text.html', 'type': 'text'}
{'name': 'f_1', 'is_hidden': False, 'required': False, 'value': None, 'attrs': {'label': 'longitude', 'class': '', 'required': True, 'id': 'id_f_1'}, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/text.html', 'type': 'text'}


{'name': 'f_0', 'is_hidden': False, 'required': False, 'value': None, 'attrs': {'label': 'latitude', 'class': '', 'required': True, 'id': 'id_f_0'}, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/text.html', 'type': 'text'}
{'name': 'f_1', 'is_hidden': False, 'required': False, 'value': None, 'attrs': {'label': 'longitude', 'class': '', 'required': True, 'id': 'id_f_1'}, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/text.html', 'type': 'text'}
```

But for some reason, the include tag doesn't behave the same way in the two loops, while it seems to be used on the same exact variable in both loops, just its mere name is different.

Why is that?

(I didn't include the code of my python files in the question in order not to make it even more lengthy and because I believe it's not needed to address the issue, but I'll be glad to add it if it's judged useful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include the subwidget template, the template is expecting an object specifically named "widget" to exist that can be used to access the properties of that subwidget.

For example, here is the source of the built-in input widget template:

```
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% if widget.value != None %} value="{{ widget.value }}"{% endif %}{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
```

In your first for loop, you are instead passing in an object named "subwidget", which the inner template does not recognize. It is looking for an object named "widget" and the only one it finds is the parent widget that contains the subwidgets. This object does not have all the required properties, which is why it renders differently than would be expected for the actual subwidgets.

I was struggling with a similar problem and was able to solve it by doing something like this:

```
{% for subwidget in widget.subwidgets %}
    {% with widget=subwidget %}
        {% include widget.template_name %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!